# Odd HDD issue, should I be worried?

Tags: ssd, hardware-failure, computer-building, repair, desktop-computer

Ok, so I get my build up and running on Friday and everything was working great.  I have two drives, a 256GB SDD connected via SATA 3(which is the boot drive.) and a 1 TB 7200RPM connected via SATA 2.  Last night my 1 TB just disappeared after I rebooted.

So I rebooted maybe 2 times and each time my 1 TB doesn't show up.  Than I trying rebooting one more time and my computer wouldn't boot because it couldn't find a bootable drive.

So I go into the BIOS and noticed that it now sees the 1 TB drive(which disappeared first.) but doesn't show the 256GB SSD.  So these are the steps I took:

- Disconnected 1 TB drive(took out power and SATA cable from 1 TB drive.), but BIOS still doesn't see SSD drive.
- Reverse cables(took 1 TB drive cables and power and connected it to SSD and took SSD and connected it to 1 TB drive.), but it still only sees the 1 TB drive.

So now this makes me think the SSD died after 2 days.  However, what has me worried is the 1 TB drive first disappeared before the SSD disappeared and didn't show up until after the SSD disappeared.

So, should I be worried?

Comment: Ok, so I updated the BIOS to the newest version and both drives are showing.  So I assume this was a bug in the BIOS?

Comment: You should post that as your answer and accept. This would help reduce up the unansered questions link on SU.;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I updated the BIOS to the newest version and both drives are showing. So I assume this was a bug in the BIOS?